Store in a table some tags in JSON while others in JSONB
I want to import a road network, and I tried to store the most used tags in JSON, while ONLY the least used in JSONB (if I use  { column = 'tags',  type = 'jsonb' }, I get all tags inside JSONB).
I haven't found any example, so I tried this; I haven't gotten any error but two JSONB empty (also I don't know how to declare two or more attributes in same JSONB)
local highway = osm2pgsql.define_table({
    name = 'highway',
    ids = { type = 'way', id_column = 'osm_id' },
    columns = {
        { column = 'name' },
        { column = 'highway', type = 'text' },
        { column = 'surface', type = 'text' },
        { column = 'oneway', type = 'bool' },
        { column = 'layer', type = 'smallint' },
    { column = 'lanes',  type = 'jsonb' },
    { column = 'maxspeed',  type = 'jsonb' },   
        { column = 'geom', type = 'linestring', not_null = true, projection = srid  },
}})

function process_highway(object, geom)
    local a = {
        name = object.tags.name,
        highway = object.tags.highway,
        surface = object.tags.surface,
        oneway = object.tags.oneway,
        layer = object.tags.layer,
        lanes = object.tags.lanes,
        maxheight = object.tags.maxheight,
        geom = geom
}


Why do you want to split the tags into two columns? Except for some very, very rare cases you should always use JSONB instead of JSON anyway.

I saw many people use json, many other jsonb. I just would like to compare both solutions to understand on my platform (still under development) which one is faster

Here is a decent description about the differences: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-json.html#:~:text=The%20json%20data%20type%20stores,since%20no%20reparsing%20is%20needed.
